# Snap Kit doesn't open Snapchat with startSending

Tags: ios, swift, snapchat

I'm trying out the Snap Kit Framework from Snapchat using their sample code but when running the code nothing happens and no error is thrown.

```
import SCSDKCreativeKit

let snap = SCSDKNoSnapContent()
snap.sticker = SCSDKSnapSticker(stickerImage: UIImage(named: "story_share.png")!)
snap.caption = "Snap on Snapchat!"
snap.attachmentUrl = profileURL.absoluteString

SCSDKSnapAPI().startSending(snap) { (error: Error?) in
    print(error)
}
```

The logs don't indicate an error either:

> myapp[853:121028] [SnapKit] Dynamic config update status: success

Things I've tried or insured are correct:

- My app is registered online with the correct bundle id, my test snapchat username and the creative kit is selected
- the development key is in the Info.plist file as `SCSDKClientId`
- `snapchat` is in the list of `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`
- the code runs on the main thread
- using their `userInteractionEnabled` trick doesn't make a difference
- I'm using carthage and embed the core and creative framework as usual

What could be the reason why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the disappointing answer that it only works using the deprecated method call:

```
SCSDKSnapAPI(content: snap).startSnapping() { (error: Error?) in
    ...
}
```

I hope that Snapchat fixes their terrible framework in the future. If anyone knows an actual solution, please let me know and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

SCSDKSnapAPI() needs to be defined as a class variable. Your code doesn't show the implementation, but I had the same issue when I instantiated SCSDKSnapAPI() in a func() instead of at the Class level.

Here's an implementation that I found which works as intended:

```
class CreateViewController: UIViewController {

fileprivate lazy var snapAPI = {
    return SCSDKSnapAPI()
}()

@IBAction func sendSnap2(_ sender: Any) {
    //self.snapAPI = SCSDKSnapAPI() <<DO NOT DO THIS>>
    let snap2 = SCSDKNoSnapContent() 
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    snapAPI.startSending(snap) { [weak self] (error: Error?) in
       self?.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error Unknown", error!)
        }
        else {
            print("no error")
        }
    }
}
```